# Serializing a wrapper object which contains a list of another object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am creating a response for an HTTP request. For example, I have a class `Cars` and `Car` whereas `Cars` contains a list of `Car`.

```
class Cars {
   private List<Car> cars
}

class Car{
  private String name;
  private String year;
}
```

In fact, by default I will get the result like:

```
{
  "cars":[
  { 
      "name":"BMW",
      "year":1999

  },
  { 
      "name":"Toyota",
      "year":1998

  }
   ]
}
```

I am expecting to set a body of ResponseEntity as a `Cars` and the client should receive the following Json.

```
[
  { 
      "name":"BMW",
      "year":1999

  },
  { 
      "name":"Toyota",
      "year":1998

  }
]
```

How can I do that with Jackson? Thanks and I hope my question is easily understandable :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should return:

```
 ResponseEntity<List<Car>>
```

Comment: This is my current solution but I wanna create a `Cars` class for a better code structure.

Comment: It won't be better. You'll have overhead and nothing else:)